# Biased coin toss

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

Let $p$, $q$ be values in $[0,1]$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$. Assume $\alpha$ and $q$ known, and that $p$ is unknown parameter we would like to estimate. A coin is tossed n times, resulting in the sequence of zero one valued random variables $X_1, X_2,...X_N$. At each toss, independently of all other tosses, the coin has probability $p$ of success with probability $\alpha$ and probability $q$ of success with probability $1-\alpha$. What is the probability function and what is the MLE of $p$?

I think the success probability should be something like $p\alpha +q(1-\alpha)$,but don't know for sure.

Comment: It's not really clear what $p$, $q$, or $\alpha$ are.  Please explain a little more.

Comment: I think you made a typo: "the coin has probability $p$ of success with probability..." $\alpha$?

Comment: So, in other words, every coin has probability $\alpha$ of being a $p$ coin, and probability $1-\alpha$ of being a $q$ coin. Or, another way to put it, each coin is a Bernoulli$(p)$ with probability $\alpha$ and Bernoulli$(q)$ with probability $1-\alpha$.

Comment: This is a qualifying exam problem and I typed it exactly as it is.

Comment: Well, 1. I think there is a typo. 2. For anyone who doesn't understand the situation, I think the interpretation is what I wrote above.

Comment: @probablyme Sorry. My bad. There was a typo and I just edited it. Sorry.

Comment: The probability of success looks right. I agree.

Comment: Since $P(X_i=1)=p\alpha + q(1-\alpha)$, we can write $P(X_i=x_i)=[p\alpha + q(1-\alpha)]^{x_i} [(1-p)\alpha + (1-q)(1-\alpha)]^{1-x_i}$ where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. The log likelihood of the sequence ends up being something like $N_1 [p\alpha + q(1-\alpha)] + N_0 \log [(1-p)\alpha + (1-q)(1-\alpha)] $ where $N_0$ and $N_1$ are the number of failures and successes respectively. Taking the derivative with respect to $p$ and setting it to zero should give you the MLE of $p$.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you!

Comment: @angryavian I just saw Albert's answer below. You guys' probability mass look similar but a little bit different. It seems both right to me now.

Comment: @Wen I think both forms are correct; the reason why it is possible for them to look so different is because $x_i$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$. I think you already saw that my form works well with the logarithm. It may be possible to do it with Albert's form, but it may be more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said $P(X=1) = p\alpha+q(1-\alpha)$

The probability mass is $f(x_i;p)=p^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i}\alpha+q^{x_i}(1-q)^{1-x_i}(1-\alpha)$

And finally the likelihood function is $L(p)=\prod_{i=1}^N f(x_i;p)$

Edit (thanks to @angryavian)

You can use $N_1$ as the number of successes in your tosses, and $N_0$ the failures. Now you have $L(p)=(p\alpha+q(1-\alpha))^{N_1}((1-p)\alpha+(1-q)(1-\alpha))^{N_0}$

In order to simplify, look for the maximum of $log(L(p))$ rather than $L(p)$.

$log(L(p))=N_1 log(p\alpha+q(1-\alpha))+N_0 log((1-p)\alpha+(1-q)(1-\alpha))$

${\partial log(L(p))\over \partial p }= N_1{\alpha \over p\alpha+q(1-\alpha)} +N_0{ -\alpha\over (1-p)\alpha+(1-q)(1-\alpha)} =0 $

Let's multiply by $(p\alpha+q(1-\alpha))((1-p)\alpha+(1-q)(1-\alpha))$

$0=N_1((1-p)\alpha+(1-q)(1-\alpha))+N_0(p\alpha+q(1-\alpha))$

$p={  N_0 q (\alpha -1)+N_1( q(1-\alpha) -1)  \over  \alpha (N_0-N_1)}$

Last equation was simplified using WolframAlpha.

And that would be your MLE.

Comment: It seems not to hard to simplify the differentiation and I just did it as angryavian's way, but his proability mass is different from yours.

Comment: I think you lost a minus sign (from the $-\alpha$) along the way.